# Export VPyhon's image as JPEG form

Tags: vpython

I'm using VPython to create some static(non-animation) 3D geometry, like an array of
cylinders, or torus. I would like to save them as .jpeg form or .png form so that I 
can put into my PPT for demonstration. Is it possible to do this? Or should I turn to
other tools like Mayavi? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way might be to display it on your screen, then take a screenshot. On a mac, that's `command + shift + 4`, not sure about Windows.